# How to make changes to this .htaccess to load my site in SSL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

My .htaccess file is shown below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Recently I have installed the SSL, so I needs to make sure that my customers connect to my website in HTTPS. So what changes I needs to make in this code to load my website in SSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load your site in SSL ,you can use

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
###########
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```